# What to do with unnecessary tags?

Tags: discussion, tags

I've found some information on the meta about merging tags by proposing synonyms, but what about the case where the asker of a question creates a tag whose necessity is debatable? If this does overlap with the content of a previous thread I'd appreciate a link (I looked and couldn't find one)

The example that made me think of this is [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/28630/linear-mixed-effects-modeling-with-twin-study-data), where the tag `twin` has been created. This tag isn't really statistical and will most likely never be used again. I suppose it could be merged with something like `multivariate` or `clustered`. In looking at the list of tags, there are many other examples like this. What is the recommended action here?

Comment: Another option would be to rename it [twin-study] and add the tag to questions like this: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/24155/why-isnt-this-a-problem-with-heritability-studies

Comment: or just merge it with the `[genetics]` tag...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Tags that aren't used by at least 1 other question within 6 months are deleted according to SE policy (see [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/privileges/create-tags)).

Comment: Thanks @gung - sometimes it's hard to find the relevant part of the FAQ :)

Comment: It was hard for me to find, too. I knew that I had seen it somewhere, but it wasn't in the FAQ; it took a bit of searching before I could find it.